Identifying short introductory book on non-commutative geometry I read c.2008
I’m trying to identify a book I remember reading and enjoying in grad school around 2008–9; I’ve forgotten its author and title, and haven’t been able to find a book matching my memories in half an hour of googling.  Memory is of course fallible so I may well have misremembered some details or conflated multiple books, but here are all the details as best as I recall them — hopefully enough are accurate to identify it:
It was an introduction to non-commutative geometry, fairly short (I think around 100–150 pages, certainly under 250), in English. It was a published book (not just a preprint or similar), I think with colour pictures on the front/back cover and possibly even a photo, and I think not from a standard big math publisher, certainly not in any of the big visually-distinctive series (Springer LNM/GTM, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Math, Memoirs of the AMS, etc).  It was breezily written, with a lot of informal intuitive description, at least in the early sections — I think even giving the first introductory examples in a non-technical, ideally-layman-accessible style, and certainly much more technically accessible throughout than e.g. Connes’ big book.  I think it had a thorough treatment of spaces of Penrose tilings as one of the chapters; I seem to recall it used the “space of triangles” as a motivating example near the beginning, and also had a nice clear treatment of Gel’fand duality, but these might be conflations from other things I read around the same time.

Do you have any memory if it was a recent book in 2008?

@LSpice: I don’t remember anything about how recent it seemed either one way or the other, I’m afraid.

Are you certain it's not An Invitation to Noncommutative Geometry by Khalkhali and Marcolli? It does discuss Penrose tilings (even has a picture of prototiles in it), it does have colour pictures on the front cover (not sure about the back), and it's from 2008. However, it doesn't match some of your other criteria: it's long (513 pages) and it's published by World Scientific.

PS: The freely downloadable standalone sample chapter is 128 pages (and it does mention Penrose tilings), maybe that's what you remember?

Some of these criteria match Masoud Khalkali's Basic Noncommutative Geometry, and you might like it also because it takes a categorical perspective, but then again it can't have been this one because it's from 2013.

@M.G.: Definitely not the Khalkhali–Marcolli Invitation — apart from differences in style/content, the book is much too big, and it can’t be the sample chapter because I really am recalling a physical published book.

@TobiasFritz: Khalkhali’s earlier Very basic noncommutative geometry (2004) matches well for material covered, but not on expository style or the look of the published version.  I think Sebastien Palcoux’s answer has correctly identified the main book I’m remembering as the early, short book of Connes, but my memory of the contents may be partly mixed up with the Khalkhali Very basic…, though I don’t explicitly remember reading that!

If you find out, could you say which one had the discussion on the space of triangles. I couldn't see that in the table of contents of the books mentioned so far.

@MichaelBächtold: I rather fear that I imported that memory from a treatment in a different formalism entirely — it’s a classic introductory example in stacks and moduli spaces, and I can’t now find any NCG presentation of anything comparable.  A shame, I’d really like to read it…

What about Alain Connes' very first book on noncommutative geometry, published in 1990 by InterEditions? The book, which is written in French, covers 239 pages and features a Penrose tiling on the cover, as shown below.

Translated text from the back cover:
This book clearly illustrates the current revival of interactions between theoretical physics and mathematics. It is aimed at mathematicians and physicists, but also at all curious scientists. Alain Connes explores the relationships between theoretical physics, geometry, and non-commutative algebra. Everyday space, indeed, is commutative, meaning that when performing algebraic operations with coordinates in this space, the order in which operands are used is indifferent. It is quite different in quantum space, which is explored using the tools of non-commutative algebra developed by the author. At the end of his reflection, the result of more than ten years of research, he proposes a "double" space that accounts for the Weinberg-Salam model, and notably the existence of Higgs bosons. This truly innovative book offers a mathematical modeling of cutting-edge research in fundamental physics, and it is expected to have a significant impact on the scientific community.

This is it, thankyou — the cover and blurb absolutely match my memory!  I haven’t yet gotten to a library to see how well the style/content match, but if not then I’m conflating memories from a second book, because this is definitely the cover of the book I’m recalling.  The strange thing is, I have no memory of it being in French, and I can’t find any record of a published English version of this — though searching is difficult, due to confusion with his much longer later book with the same title, which is also why I overlooked this in my own searching.

Amazon apparently has an English translation - https://www.amazon.com/Noncommutative-Geometry-Alain-Connes/dp/012185860X

@thurizas That link is to the 680-page long expanded version. As the preface states "Although this book is based on Alain Connes, GEOMETRIE NON COMMUTATIVE, InterEditions, 1990, and its English translation by Sterling Berberian, more than two thirds of the material is new with this work." Berberian's translation does not appear to have been published in standalone form.

https://alainconnes.org/wp-content/uploads/book94bigpdf.pdf

Having checked this out from the library and started re-reading it, it’s certainly one half of what I’d remembered (the physical book and discursive style are just as I recalled) — but my memory of the contents is clearly mixed up with some more mathematically-elementary introduction, I think possibly either the Khalkhali Very basic… or the early chapters of the book by Gracia-Bondía, Várilly, and Figueroa.

This question is a lot of fun. Let me take my chance. The book was

An Introduction to Noncommutative Spaces and their Geometries by Giovanni Landi.


Not this, I’m afraid — this is a good fit on content, but very different style (accessible but formal) and visual vibe (extremely standard math publisher look).  This was the nearest match I’d found in my own searching, and I’d meant to note it in the question but forgot!
